# Why does UPDATE .WRITE() only work if I use [column].WRITE(), but not [table].[column].WRITE()?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm executing an UPDATE .WRITE() statement and have found out that it obviously only works if you define it like this:

```
string sql = "UPDATE [dbo].[Table] SET [Column].WRITE(@data, @offset, @count) WHERE ...";
...
sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

However, if I use `[dbo].[Table].[Column].WRITE(...)` or `[Table].[Column].WRITE(...)`, an exception is thrown:

```
Incorrect syntax near 'WRITE'.

Stack trace:
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, DbAsyncResult result)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(DbAsyncResult result, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   ...
```

Why is that? It doesn't seem very consistent with the usual way one would construct SQL statements. Is there any point for this seemingly exceptional convention, where you are obviously not allowed to explicitly specify table name and schema?

Comment: @marc_s I'm using it to update a varbinary(max) column in chunks, as it is possible for it to be very long (100MB+). Is there another way to do this, because as far as I know, .WRITE was the usual way?

Comment: @marc_s According to the documentation it is the WRITETEXT and UPDATETEXT methods that will be depreciated along with the ntext, text, and image data types, not the WRITE method which is used for the varchar(max), nvarchar(max), and varbinary(max) data types.
[Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/ms177523.aspx#LOBValues)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> It doesn't seem very consistent ...

It is actually consistent with the rest of the [`SET` clause](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/ms177523.aspx):

```
SET
    { column_name = { expression | DEFAULT | NULL }
      | { udt_column_name.{ { property_name = expression
                            | field_name = expression }
                            | method_name ( argument [ ,...n ] )
                          }
      }
      | column_name { .WRITE ( expression , @Offset , @Length ) }
      | @variable = expression
      | @variable = column = expression
      | column_name { += | -= | *= | /= | %= | &= | ^= | |= } expression
      | @variable { += | -= | *= | /= | %= | &= | ^= | |= } expression
      | @variable = column { += | -= | *= | /= | %= | &= | ^= | |= } expression
    } [ ,...n ]
```

That is, it's **never** valid, in the `SET` clause, to specify a table or schema on the left side of the assignment (You can, of course, reference other tables by full name or alias, in the `expression`s on the right hand side). The table to update has already been identified between `UPDATE` and `SET`.